# Using CreateWindowEx to Make a Message-Only Window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to use `CreateWindowEx` to generate a message-only window:

```
_hWnd = CreateWindowEx( 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

When my application executes this line it always returns `_hWnd = 0`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should be able to call GetLastError() to get more info.

Comment: There is example code to do this via MFC [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/messageonly.aspx). This should hide some of the Win32 API parameter complexity.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`lpClassName` shouldn't be `NULL`. Register class using `RegisterClassEx` function and pass it to `CreateWindowEx`.

```
static const char* class_name = "DUMMY_CLASS";
WNDCLASSEX wx = {};
wx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wx.lpfnWndProc = pWndProc;        // function which will handle messages
wx.hInstance = current_instance;
wx.lpszClassName = class_name;
if ( RegisterClassEx(&wx) ) {
  CreateWindowEx( 0, class_name, "dummy_name", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, NULL, NULL );
}
```

Comment: Oh, dread!  I was hoping to avoid `RegisterClass` as the documentation for it is very ambiguous.  Do you know of a good example?

Comment: Without a class, how else would you feed the window procedure to the system? (I know about subclassing via GetWindowLong())

Comment: @Kirill V. Lyadvinsky: Is `current_instance` important?  How does it get set?

Comment: If you don't want to register the window class, you can use the pre-defined `STATIC` class (used for text labels and image boxes). If you don't give it a `hWndParent` parameter, it creates a standalone window!

Comment: @Kirill V. Lyadvinsky: Odd, it started working when I copied the example as given.  It does work, though, so you get the points.  Cheers!

Comment: You may use any of standard window classes, like BUTTON, as well.

Comment: If you don't register a class there is no way to retrieve the messages.

Comment: This is quite an old answer. Is it still up to date?

Answer (score -10):

According to [the Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#system) the class name should be "Message".

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: The table listing `Message` window class is described as "The following table describes the system classes that are available only for use by the system. They are listed here for completeness sake." so I don't think Windows expects you to use `Message` window class. It would be useless anyway as then you would have to sub-class to provide own window procedure...

Comment: downgrading to make sure others don't consider that to be a valid answer. See the comment above for a reason (it's a system-only class, can't be used by non-system)