# Can't get the handle of a Cwnd Class in MFC Windowless Activex?

Tags: c++, mfc, activex, atl

I have asked two questions earlier about this  and for each post there was some solutions i tried them, but the problem still exist.

My first question was : why a windowless Activex does not  return the Handle. the suggestion was "change the creation setting an make windowless activate off, i have tried it but still `m_hWnd` property has returned zero as `GetSafeHwnd()` method has did.

the second one was the same question this one focused on COleControl class and it's ancestor CWnd. the solution was as this **"Create invisible window somewhere in your control initialization code. Handle the messages sent to this window, and call controls methods directly"**. so i did that but the created class still returns zero handle.

here is my new invisible class source:

```
// moWind.cpp : implementation file
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PINActive.h"
#include "moWind.h"
#include "include\xfspin.h"
#include <math.h>
// moWind

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(moWind, CWnd)

moWind::moWind(){}

moWind::~moWind(){}

//=============================================================
LRESULT moWind::OnExecuteEvent (WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WFSRESULT *pResult = (WFSRESULT *)lParam;
    CString EK=_T("");
    CString str;
    int reskey=0;
    if (pResult->u.dwEventID=WFS_EXEE_PIN_KEY)
    {       
        LPWFSPINKEY pressedkey;
        pressedkey=(LPWFSPINKEY)pResult->lpBuffer;

    reskey = log10((double)pressedkey->ulDigit) / log10((double)2);

        EK.Format("%d",reskey);
        xfsOnKeyEvent->OnKeyRecieved(reskey);
    }
    else
    {
        str.Format("ExecuteEvent:  ID = %d\r\n", pResult->u.dwEventID);
    }
    MessageBox("a Execute message Recieved");
    return 0;
}
    
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(moWind, CWnd)
        
    ON_MESSAGE(WFS_EXECUTE_EVENT,OnExecuteEvent)
    
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

and this is .h file of the class:

```
// moWind.h
class IXFSEvents
{
protected:
    IXFSEvents(){};
    virtual ~IXFSEvents(){};
public:
    virtual void OnKeyRecieved(int key)=0;
};

class moWind : public CWnd
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(moWind)

public:
    moWind();
    virtual ~moWind();
    void Register(IXFSEvents* obj)
    {
        xfsOnKeyEvent= obj;
    }
protected:
    IXFSEvents* xfsOnKeyEvent;
    LRESULT OnExecuteEvent (WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

and at the end here this the way I've used this class in my Activex:
in the myActivex.h file:

## include "moWind.h"

```
class CmyActivexCtrl : public COleControl, public IXFSEvents
{
...
Class definition
...
protected:
      moWind tmpWind;
 .
 .
 };
```

finally in the creation method of myActivex i have initialized the  component callback method an wanted to get it's Handle as this:

```
CmyActivexCtrl::CmyActivexCtrl()
{
    InitializeIIDs(&IID_DmyActivex, &IID_DmyActivexEvents);
    tmpWind.Register(this);
    myOtherComponent.WindowsHandle=tmpWind.GetSafeHwnd(); //here my Cwnd derived class returns zero
        //my other component gets the handle and call an API with it to register 
        //the given handle and force the API to send the messages to that handle.
}
```

Comment: Is there any body here to listen to my story?  :D

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question again?

Comment: Well if it is a windowless ActiveX control it naturally won't have any window handle. What do you need the handle for? There are a lot of COM interfaces to let you achieve things without a window handle. Please specify.

Comment: I need to call an API which would registers the handle to send a specific WM_USER windows message through it to the control or window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you need a window handle to be able to receive user messages through it, you always have an option of creating a helper window, such as message only window, see [Using CreateWindowEx to Make a Message-Only Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081334/using-createwindowex-to-make-a-message-only-window).

For your windowless control it is okay to not have any window handle at all, so you cannot really rely on handle availability unless you own a window yourself.

Comment: so how i can handle the messages through  the created window in that manner?

Comment: The same way as with any window - define handlers and have them called. First chance google result gave me this one: [How to make a Message Only Window](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/messageonly.aspx) and it shows a window class `CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass` which is something about what you need, in MFC. ATL code would perhaps be even simpler.