# WinAPI device notification - not entering message loop

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to detect when a USB drive is inserted. Right now, I'm creating a dummy window and `RegisterDeviceNotification`ing it. However, I don't think my approach is correct, as the window doesn't seem to be receiving messages.

```
#include <iostream>
#define WINVER 0x501
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbt.h>
#include "devicehandler.h"
#include "remover.h"

DeviceHandler::DeviceHandler(Remover* remover)
{
    this->remover = remover;
    this->hWnd = this->createHandleWindow();
    this->registerDeviceHandler();
    this->messageLoop(this->hWnd);
}

DeviceHandler::~DeviceHandler()
{
    this->unregisterDeviceHandler();
}

void DeviceHandler::messageLoop(HWND hWnd)
{
    std::cerr << "Entering message loop." << std::endl; // Gets here!

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, this->hWnd, 0, 0)) {
        std::cerr << "Loop!" << std::endl; // Does not get here!
        switch (msg.message) {
            case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
                {
                    PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR pHdr = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR) msg.lParam;
                    switch(msg.wParam) {
                        case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                            std::cerr << "Device added!" << std::endl;
                            break;
                        default:
                            std::cerr << "Other device event." << std::endl;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

HWND DeviceHandler::createHandleWindow()
{
    std::cerr << "Creating handle window... ";

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(NULL, NULL, WS_ICONIC, 0, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,
                             NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);

    std::cerr << "done!" << std::endl;
    return hWnd;
}

void DeviceHandler::registerDeviceHandler()
{
    std::cerr << "Device notification handling... ";
    // GUID guid = { 0xa5dcbf10, 0x6530, 0x11d2, { 0x90, 0x1f, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x4f, 0xb9, 0x51, 0xed } };
    GUID guid = { 0x25dbce51, 0x6c8f, 0x4a72, { 0x8a, 0x6d, 0xb5, 0x4c, 0x2b, 0x4f, 0xc8, 0x35 } };
    DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE notificationFilter;
    ZeroMemory(&notificationFilter, sizeof(notificationFilter));
    notificationFilter.dbcc_size       = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
    notificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
    notificationFilter.dbcc_classguid  = guid;

    this->deviceNotifier = RegisterDeviceNotification(this->hWnd,
                                                      &notificationFilter,
                                                      DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
    std::cerr << "done!" << std::endl;
}

void DeviceHandler::unregisterDeviceHandler()
{
    UnregisterDeviceNotification(this->deviceNotifier);
}
```

I'm guessing that this is not the right place to put the message loop, but I'm not very good with WinAPI. How do I get my program to enter the message loop? (And also preferably register device notifications.)

Comment: Improve your error handling, never assume that a Windows api function succeeds.  You'll no doubt see that you didn't actually create the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be creating a [message only Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#message_only). It can receive messages it registers like device notification and power events, but it will never be shown.

Message only [window must be registered with RegisterClassEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081334/using-createwindowex-to-make-a-message-only-window).

With you window class registered, you then pass your window class name to CreateWindowEx along with HWND_MESSAGE as a parent. Your CreateWindow should use [`CreateWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead to look like this :

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, myClassName, _T("This is not the class name"), 
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, 0, this);
```

You will still use GetMessage along with [TranslateMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [DispathMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which will call your WNDPROC like a callback. Nothing wrong with that, but you loose the pointer to your DeviceHandler class in your windows procedure.

This is why you pass `this` as the last parameter of `CreateWindowEx`. You can retreive it when you receive the `WM_CREATE` message and set it to your windows class user data with [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `GWLP_USERDATA`. Every call after that will retreive the pointer with [`GetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and cast it to a DeviceHandler object.

Here is [a good example of the technique](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/303854-pointer-to-wndproc-in-a-class/).

To [play by the rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/03/384285.aspx), you should register your own window class to use `GWLP_USERDATA`, although it should still work using the `STATIC` window class.

Final note : be sure to call [DefWindowProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for messages you don't handle.

Comment: This works, but it forces me to use a callback, which is difficult to integrate without adding global state. Is there any way to use `GetMessage` instead of a callback?

Comment: I beleive you must use a callback, actually called a window procedure. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is that your window is not created because you didn't specified valid class name. `HWND` returned in this case is `NULL` and device fails to register it and send messages to it.

As proposed in other answer you could use [Message-Only Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#message_only) for purpose to receive device notifications. But would like to mention that registering window class is not necessary in this case, you could use predefined class name, e.g. `STATIC` (as you don't need actually to specify your own window proc):

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "STATIC", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, 0, 0);
```